# Delete Records past 6 month Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to delete all records past 6 months in my table for ORACLE.

I currently have

```
delete from table t 
where to_date(substr(t.DATE_SENT,1,10),'MM/DD/YYYY')  < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6);
```

The string format in this table is `'12/21/2015 12:00:00 AM'`.

NOTE I understand that this should be a DATETIME and not a varchar2 but it just happens to be a varchar2 so I am trying to find a work around it for now.

This query seems to somewhat work for select * but then crashes with SQL

> Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess that you have values lie 1/1/2015 in the data.

Comment: Try to find records where the date format doesn't match with `select * from table where not regexp_like(date_sent, '^[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{1,2}/[[:digit:]]{4}')`.

Answer (score 2):

No need of `SUBSTR`. directly use `TO_DATE` on the format.

```
DELETE FROM t
      WHERE TO_DATE (t.DATE_SENT, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') <
               ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -6);
```

Comment: `HH24` and `AM` do not make sense together; did you mean `HH12`?

Comment: That was a mistake. I modified already..But somehow feel the data is the  issue here..

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Close but not close enough. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @TroyReynolds - if you confirmed that the solution does indeed work, please don't forget to mark as "Correct Answer". Future visitors of this thread will then instantly know that the answer did work.